# PIG Script to aggregate data while grouping

Tags: apache-pig

for the following relation

```
H = foreach G generate word,date;
```

This is my data in PIG.

```
(sick,21-05-2013)
(sick,21-05-2013)
(sick,21-05-2013)
(sick,17-05-2013)
(sick,19-05-2013)
(sickness,21-05-2013)
(sickness,21-05-2013)
(sickness,21-05-2013)
(sickness,17-05-2013)
(sickness,19-05-2013)
```

What script should i write to get my output as

```
(sick,21-05-2013,3)
(sick,17-05-2013,1)
(sick,19-05-2013,1)
(sickness,21-05-2013,3)
(sickness,17-05-2013,1)
(sickness,19-05-2013,1)
```

I am totally confused not able to rack my brains around it. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give the result i need

```
I = Group H by (word,date);
J = FOREACH I generate group,COUNT($1);
dump J;
```

Comment: This will not work as you requested it should give ((word,date), count) not (word,date,count).  You will need to add an additional flatten statement